# Colapse layered navigation when new item is clicked, Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a layered navigation

[image: The Menu]

The problem is when i click 2 items that have children they both stay open making the menu have a scrollbar which i don't want (I know i can hide the scrollbar but i dont want to do that).

[image: With Children showing]

How can i get it to close 1 when another is clicked?

Here is a section of my menu:

```html
<li class='nav-item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Stock Management'>
  <a class='nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseMulti33' data-parent='#exampleAccordion'>
  <i class='fas fa-fw fa-lock'></i>
  <span class='nav-link-text'>Admin</span>
 </a>
 <ul class='sidenav-second-level collapse' id='collapseMulti33'>
  <li>
   <a href='/admin/settings.php'>Settings</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href='/admin/logs.php'>Logs</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href='/monitor/index.php?disp=bootstrap'>System Information</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `data-parent` attribute on your collapsible elements (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example) with a proper id selector.

Should look like this (using `#offcanvasNav` as parent):

```
<ul id="offcanvasNav">
  <li class='nav-item' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Stock Management'>
    <a class='nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseMulti33' data-parent='#offcanvasNav'>
      <i class='fas fa-fw fa-lock'></i>
      <span class='nav-link-text'>Admin</span>
    </a>
    <ul class='sidenav-second-level collapse' id='collapseMulti33'>
      <li>
        <a href='/admin/settings.php'>Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='/admin/logs.php'>Logs</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='/monitor/index.php?disp=bootstrap'>System Information</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  [...]
</ul>
```

If you want to use javascript you could also use the methods from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#methods to close all other collapsibles.

[image]

Comment: I'm already using data-parent i believe, #exampleAccordian. This is the parents id and data-parent in all menu items. I'm going to try the javascript but i'm really not familiar with it.

Comment: @CarlPiper then it should already work. A typo in the id somewhere maybe?

Comment: No no typo, i'll look into it. At least now i know it should be working

Comment: Ive made an edit to the original question and shown the code in inspect element as the way we've done out menu is with php, and i cant easily copy and paste to here. but if you could have a look and soo if you can spot the issue it would be greatly appreciated